# can add increment number in nft name when mint based on mint order?

Tags: anchor, metaplex, nft

i made a contract for the user to be able to mint nft using anchor + metaplex.

can i auto increment the nft name when prompted depending on the order?

ex : Name #1, Name #2, Name #3, Name #4, ..... Name #n

Answer (score 1):

Certainly! You'll just need to store that number somewhere on-chain, likely in some other account. When minting, you include this account in your program instruction, and your program increments the number on a successful mint.